# Custom token authentication with Django and Firebase

Tags: python, django, firebase, firebase-authentication

Sure, here's a sample Stack Overflow question for the problem of custom token authentication with Django and Firebase:

Title: Custom token authentication with Django and Firebase

Problem:

I'm trying to implement custom token authentication with Django and Firebase. I've followed the steps in the documentation, but I'm still having trouble getting it to work. When I try to sign in with the custom token, I get an error that says "Invalid custom token."

```
# Django server code

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from rest_framework import permissions, views, status
from firebase_admin import auth

class CustomTokenLogin(views.APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request):
        username = request.data.get('username')
        password = request.data.get('password')

        if username is None or password is None:
            return Response({'error': 'Missing username or password'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)

            # Create a custom token using Firebase Admin SDK
            custom_token = auth.create_custom_token(user.uid)

            return Response({'token': custom_token})
        else:
            return Response({'error': 'Invalid username or password'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

for verify token

```
class ProfileView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):

        try:
            decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(request.headers.get('Authorization', ''))
            user_id = decoded_token['uid']
            user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)  # Fetch the user from the database

            # Fetch user profile data
            profile_data = {
                'username': user.username,
                'email': user.email,
                'first_name': user.first_name,
                'last_name': user.last_name  # Include other profile information as needed
            }

            return Response(profile_data)
        except auth.InvalidIdTokenError:
            return Response({'error': 'Invalid Firebase token'}, status=401)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({'error': 'User not found'}, status=404)
```

I expected the user to be signed in successfully after verifying the custom token.